# use same output in two processes in nextflow dsl2

Tags: nextflow

This is my workflow:

```
pre_align()
pre_align.out.single_fastqs.view()
get_fq_info(pre_align.out.single_fastqs)

align_bwa(get_fq_info.out.fq_info)

align_bowtie2(get_fq_info.out.fq_info)
```

where I want to use the same output from `get_fq_info` as input for either `align_bwa` and align_bowtie2`.

As it's shown here **only align_bwa is executed**. If I comment `align_bwa` THEN `align_bowtie2` gets executed.

How can I fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this problem in the past by [duplicating the output channel](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-use-the-same-channel-multiple-times) of the desired process in order to feed the same output into multiple downstream processes.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, DSL2 should be able to handle this. Have you specified an output qualifier for your process `get_fq_info` (e.g. `path`)? I ran into a similar issue when I forgot to specify it.

For example, this will result in the error `process align_bowtie2 declares 1 input channel but 0 were specified`:

```
process get_fq_info {
   input:
   path reads

   output:
   "output.txt"

   shell:
   """
   myprocess.sh ${reads} > output.txt
   """
}
```

And is probably solved by this:

````
process get_fq_info {
   input:
   path reads

   output:
   path "output.txt"

   shell:
   """
   myprocess.sh ${reads} > output.txt
   """

```
````